# Facebook connect in frame (X-Frame Options)

Tags: facebook, iframe

Some of you have they set up a Facebook application? (I mean, called a website in Facebook Iframe) 
If so, I encounter a problem with the connection in the iframe (outside, no worries). 
In console, I get: "Refused to display '/ * url * /' in a frame Because It set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'.". 
After research, it would be a configuration problem. 
My boss is on a shared server, it was informed that the problem would be "maybe" set passing on a VPS. 
I wanted to know if you had this problem, and if you could solve it one way or another, or if the transfer to VPS was mandatory.

Thanks

Comment: Is this upon gathering the login permissions?

Comment: The X-Frame-Option is something Facebook set. And nothing you can change. We don't want you to iframe the dialog box so that is why we set that property

Comment: I can understand, but if is it a facebook option as you said, how other applications can set a Facebook connect in canvas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix my issue.

Using Symfony2 and HWIOAUTH Bundle, I was thinking I don't have to use Javascript SDK. But I finally implement that code, and now it's ok.

Thanks